# How OS restricts user process from accessing kernel memory

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, kernel, paging

In 32bit Linux(or windows, whatever), a user process can not access the
kernel address space. say 0xC0100000 (in 3:1 split such as linux) or
0x80E00000 (1:1 split such as windows).

I know the following code from user application will raise segmentation fault.

```
int* a = 0xC0100000;
int b = *a;
```

however, I am not 100% sure about the actual reason.
I assume that if we try to execute the above code, MMU will raise segfault because the corresponding Page Table Entry of virtual address 0xC0100000 has supervisor bit flag.
is this 100% correct? If this is correct, how can OS prevent a process accessing kernel virtual address via TLB cache?

I also think that using segmentation, the same restriction could be implemented.
i.e. if the DS, CS, SS ... entry of GDT has address limit of 0xC0000000. accessing 0xC0100000 will fail from the segmentation process regardless of Page Table setting. 
please fix me if i'm wrong.

some advice would be nice.
thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would the TLB affect this?

Comment: because if the TLB hits, the MMU will not walk the page table which means it cannot check the page table entry flag.

Comment: @daehee the TLB is a cache of page table entries, it contains the same flags.

Comment: MMU does not "segfault", it sends a processor exception. That exception triggers an interrupt which is processed by the kernel, which later one could send a  `SIGSEGV` *signal* to the application.

Comment: @daehee: No, while it is right that a TLB hit will result in not pagewalking, but the permissions are cached as well.

Comment: oh, I didn't new TLB entry has PTE flag as well, then there would be no problem. but still, I think in x86, the memory access restriction could be achieved via segmentation(configuring the base, limit of segment descriptor in GDT) as well.. am I wrong?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch of course thats right, I was saying that MMU will trigger something that eventually raises SIGSEGV to the process.

Answer (score 1):

What matters is only the [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) as seen by the application in [user space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) (or user mode). Kernel address space is not visible to applications (only to the kernel, e.g. when it is executing [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_calls)).

When execution switches from user mode to kernel mode (e.g. thru a syscall or an interrupt) the [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) changes state, to give access to the kernel pages. Details are processor specific (not the same on x86 and on ARM), and by definition not visible to application code. See wikipage on [page fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault).

Comment: However, in e.g. Linux, each process's virtual address space is divided (at `PAGE_OFFSET`) into the part that the user can touch, and the part that only the kernel can touch.  The OP is asking how that's achieved.